# Bootstrap 4 - Right Align Navbar Items

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm trying to align my navbar items to the right in bootstrap 4 alpha 6.

I'd like to have everything aligned right, except for the brand/title.

#### This is what my code looks like:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Oliver</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
  <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">About <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#projects">Projects</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can add `.justify-content-end` to the `.navbar-collapse` element. And I'm assuming you also want to move the mobile toggle menu items to the right. To do that, add `.align-items-end` to `.navbar-nav`

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Oliver</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav align-items-end">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">About <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#projects">Projects</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: This may have worked in 4.0.0 alpha, however the newer v4 beta releases have introduced many breaking changes. On 4.0 beta 3 this solution no longer works.